# JQuery HTML editor css standard compliant

Tags: jquery, html, standards-compliance

I'd simply like not to have a JQuery based HTML editor that use `<b>`, `<i>`, `<font>` and all those deprecated tags. Can you help me please?

Comment: Which ones have you already tried?

Comment: `b` and `i` elements are not deprecated by W3C, please check [Index of Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html). Though they shouldn't be available in an HTML editor, I'm OK with that :) What content writers usually mean by bold is emphasis and thus `strong`; `b` use is (way too) subtle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bespin is my choice http://mozillalabs.com/bespin/ - it's not wysiwyg though, more like textmate in a browser. There is a jQuery extension here to make using it with jQuery simpler:
http://www.balupton.com/sandbox/jquery-sparkle/demo/#bespin

TinyMCE I believe also can do what you want with appropriate options enabled.
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a small embeddable editor to use inside of a website, your best option is probably CKEditor (http://ckeditor.com/). Though it itself isn't written in JQuery, [there are JQuery hooks available](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery).

[1]: